# Заполнения 100% блока при не известном количестве контента js css

Tags: javascript, css

Есть блок, в который добавляют изображения  юзеры. У блока фиксированная ширина. При добавлении малого количества изображений, блок должен либо выравниваться по высоте, либо распределять контент по всему родительскому блоку. Надеюсь доходчиво..выручайте!)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то flex-box в помощь.

```css
.block {
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, я такое решение применял..но там скорей нужно другой подход..по типу ловить js ской высоту и ресайзить блок). спасибо)